# time_left function in Timer node not working, "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'time_left' in base 'Timer'."

Tags: godot

```
extends Area2D

export var rot_speed = 2.6
export var thrust = 500
export var max_vel = 400
export var friction = 0.65

export (PackedScene) var bullet
onready var bullet_container = get_node("BulletContainer")
onready var gun_timer = get_node("gunTimer")


var screen_size
var rot = 0
var pos = Vector2()
var acc = Vector2()
var vel = Vector2()

func _ready():
    screen_size = get_viewport_rect().size
    pos = screen_size / 2
    position = pos

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("player_shoot"):
        if gun_timer.time_left() == 0:
        shoot()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("player_left"):
        rot -= rot_speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("player_right"):
        rot += rot_speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("player_thrust"):
        acc = Vector2(0, -thrust).rotated(rot)
    else:
        acc = Vector2(0, 0)

    acc -= vel*friction
    vel += acc * delta
    pos += vel * delta

    if pos.x >= screen_size.x:
        pos.x = 0
    if pos.x < 0:
        pos.x = screen_size.x
    if pos.y >= screen_size.y:
        pos.y = 0
    if pos.y < 0:
        pos.y = screen_size.y


    position = pos

    rotation = rot

func shoot():
    gun_timer.start()
    var b = bullet.instance()
    bullet_container.add_child(b)
    b.start_at(rotation, 
    get_node("bullet_spawn_pos").global_position)
```

This is the script for my player. My player is shooting bullets when i input shoot, but i want a timer that limits the rate at witch the bullets can be fired. So i create a timer node but when i call the time_left function i get an error that says that there is no such function "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'time_left' in base 'Timer'." See if statement line 26.

I have tried calling the function from different places but i always get the error. I am new to godot and would appreciate any help i could get.

Comment: `time_left` is not a function, it is a property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use timer.is_stopped()  and you can have it on the input line add and timer.is_stopped() so when the timer is at zero you can shoot again, but this also means you have to tell it to start the timer in the input function.

And also make sure the timer is a one shot timer